# How to insert UTC value in timestampz column

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.5

I have defined a table as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE mytbl (
    my_timestamp timestamptz NOT NULL DEFAULT now(),
    CONSTRAINT my_tbl_my_timestamp_check CHECK ((date_part('timezone'::text, my_timestamp) = '0'::double precision))
);
```

As you can see that a check is in place to ensure that only UTC values can be inserted into the column **my_timestamp**

Now I can insert UTC values successfully if I do the following:

```
SET timezone = 'UTC';
INSERT INTO mytbl (my_timestamp) VALUES (NOW());
```

But what I want to do is to be able to insert UTC values in the column **my_timestamp** without changing the timezone using **SET timezone = 'UTC';**

I have tried the following but it violates the check:

```
INSERT INTO mytbl (my_timestamp) VALUES (timezone('utc', now()));
```

Can anyone please explain what I'm missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PostgreSQL internally converts all timestamps to UTC for the type `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE` also known as `TIMESTAMPTZ`. This is because postgres does not store the timezone information.

[From the docs:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/datatype-datetime.html)

> For timestamp with time zone, the internally stored value is always in
>   UTC (Universal Coordinated Time, traditionally known as Greenwich Mean
>   Time, GMT). An input value that has an explicit time zone specified is
>   converted to UTC using the appropriate offset for that time zone. If
>   no time zone is stated in the input string, then it is assumed to be
>   in the time zone indicated by the system's TimeZone parameter, and is
>   converted to UTC using the offset for the timezone zone.

In other words, you do not have to explicitly convert the timestamps to UTC before saving. PostgreSQL will do that for you automatically.

Comment: So there is no way to do what I'm trying to do? for example when the timezone is 'US/Pacific' and I run the query INSERT INTO mytbl (my_timestamp) VALUES (NOW()); it fails due to the check I have implemented but works if I change the timezone to 'UTC' it works

Comment: What you're missing is the meaning of the timezone portion of the timestamp. By defining the column as timestamptz you have instructed Postgres to store it as GMT+00. Postgres, however, does not store the offset (US/Pacific dst -07), it's used to adjust the time in order to get to +00. Your check constraints only permits times already at +00 BEFORE applying offset. That why "set timezone='utc' works as you've essentially told Postres that is the timezone it's in.